# onClick not firing when clicking on component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

A well covered topic, but my event handle is not being triggered when clicking on the component and can't see what's going wrong. Any ideas? Is it something to do with mapping through the array elements?

```
function App() {

  const [fileTree, setFileTree] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const data = getFileTree();
    setFileTree(data)
  }, []);

  const handleClick = () => {
    console.log('clicked')
  }

  const mapThroughTreeItem = () => {
    return fileTree.root.map((el, i) => <FileTreeItem
      item={el}
      key={i}
      onClick={handleClick}
    />)
  }

  if (fileTree) {
    return (
      <>
        {mapThroughTreeItem()}
      </>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <>
        Loading..
    </>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: What's your `FileTreeItem` component look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FileTreeItem seems to be a custom element, how are you handling the click event inside this component ?

You should probably have something like

```
function FileTreeItem({onClick}) {
    return (
        <div onClick={onClick}></div>
    )
}
```

You can't register events directly on a custom element as they will be entirely replaced in the DOM by their render implementation.